# Checking for the presence of a completed column company in AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please tell me how to check if the user has the organization field filled in

I am making a phone book on MVC 5. There is a model and a controller.

Model

```
     public class Person
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string ExtensionPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        //public string Title { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentNumber { get; set; }
        public string Subdivision { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

 public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Home(string department)
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetPeople();
            return View(persons);
        }

        public static List<Person> GetPeople()
        {

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            var path = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "RCSON.local", "OU=RCSON, DC=RCSON, DC=local");

            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(path);
            user.Enabled = true;

            //user.Name = "*";
            //user.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "*";
            //user.EmailAddress = "*";
            //user.Description = "";
            
            var search = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
            search.QueryFilter = user;
            var results = search.FindAll();
            foreach (UserPrincipal item in results)
            {
                var directoryEntry = item.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                people.Add(new Person
                {
                    DisplayName = item.Name,
                    PhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                    ExtensionPhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                    Email = item.EmailAddress,
                    Office = directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value as string,
                    Department = directoryEntry.Properties["subdivision"].Value as string,
                    //Title = directoryEntry.Properties["title"].Value as string,
                    DepartmentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["departmentNumber"].Value),
                    Subdivision = directoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value as string,
                    Manager = directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value as string,
                    Mobile = directoryEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value as string,
                    EmployeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["employeeNumber"].Value)
                });
            }
            return people;
        }
}
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv2vh.jpg

How to filter users who have an organization name.

Comment: you want to filter by a property? i dont understand. what is organization name?

Comment: AD has a "Company" or "organization" field. I need to select users by this field

Comment: What is AD. And where company or organization field? I can't see in this post.

Comment: AD is Active Directory.